# How to make matlab repeat a procedure independently?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, random

I have a matrix like this:

A =

```
 1     1     1     0     1
 0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1
```

I want to replace for example 30% of 1 elements in this matrix with 0 randomly and repeat this procedure independently 10 times for instance, and at the end of the work I must have 10 independent matrices which each one of them should has 30% of 1 elements less than the original matrix.

here's the code I use to do this:

```
for i=1:10 
f=.3;
A_ones=find(A);
n = round(f*length(A_ones));
A_ones_change = randsample(A_ones,n);
A(A_ones_change) = 0;
end
A
```

But the thing that matlab does with this code is that it takes the original matrix A at the begining and replaces 30% of its 1 elements with 0. But for the second time it takes the resultant matrix from previous step as A (not the original matrix) and replaces 30% of remained 1 elements in that matrix with 0 and does it again and again for 10 times and at the end it gives me only 1 matrix like below:

A =

```
 0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

How can I solve this problem and make matlab to do this procedure on 'original matrix A' for each i?

Comment: It's because you are overwriting your matrix. Distinguish your original `A` and your resampled `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `A` is changing every time because of the last line in your loop `A(A_ones_change) = 0;`. Change it to some copy of A (say, `A1 = A`) you make in the beginning of the loop.

Comment: cell arrays should help: `A{i} = A`

Comment: Since your matrices are of equal size, you can pre-allocate a 3D matrix to store each independent matrix of yours. `B = zeros([size(A) 10]);`.

Comment: @Jacob thanks a lot for answering my question, I did what you said and the loop worked correctly but at the end it gives me still only 1 matrix as result not 10 matrices.

Comment: Yes, look at the comments by @Amro and me ; you need to store the matrices someplace after you generate them. Create a cell array called `B` and let `B{i} = A1;` where `A1` is the new matrix.